# Transactional annotation slow down the performance after jpa implementation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am upgrading my application, currently it is using Hibernate 3 and now moving to jpa-hibernate 4.
We have one utility class `BaseDAO` which is used for all database related operations like `executeQuery`, `executeUpdate` and all. The session is also managed there only.
Currently where we are using get methods to show data, or single update/create/delete operation then we are not creating transactions, the `BaseDAO` does it.
Now since we are migrating to JPA we need transactional for persists call.So I have added `@Transactional` at `BaseDAO` at class level, and when I add it, the application works fine but the functionalities where lot of interaction was there with DB it got slowed down. There is one report which earlier used to take 1 min, and now it takes 1.4 mins.

**Hibernate Template method**

```
public class BaseDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport {

public List executeQueryPaging(final String hql, final Object[] params, final Integer[] pagingParam) {
        List results = null;
        results = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {

            public Object doInHibernate(Session session) {
                Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

                if (params != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                        query.setParameter(i, params[i]);
                    }
                }
                query.setFirstResult(pagingParam[0]);
                query.setMaxResults(pagingParam[1]);

                return query.list();
            }
        });
        return results;
    }
}
```

**JPA method**

```
@Transactional
public class BaseDAO {

public List executeQueryPaging(final String hql, final Object[] params, final Integer[] pagingParam) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql);
        List list = null;

        if (params != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                query.setParameter(i + 1, params[i]);
            }
        }
        if (pagingParam != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(pagingParam[0]);
            query.setMaxResults(pagingParam[1]);
        }
        list = (List) query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Opening/starting a tx can be a long operation, especially if you also aren't using a connection pool (which you really should be using. If you are doing a lot of individual operations you want to have the whole method being transactional and not the individual repository/dao methods. Making the whole thing transactional will reuse the connection and transaction.

Comment: We are using C3P0 connection pool. I am not sure how the current system works fine and faster than the new JPA

Comment: As you are only selecting data try @Transactional(readOnly = true) This is an hint for Hibernate that the data is read only.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - I had tried with readOnly = true also and it had improved some performance, but still it doesnt match the performance it was with HibernateDAOSupport.